# How to use sql math function in dql (symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('select cp from Temp\TempAppBundle\Entity\ClinicProfile cp INNER JOIN cp.users u left JOIN cp.specializations s where cp.latitude is not null and cp.city = ?1 order by (sqrt(pow((radians(cp.longitude) - radians(?2))*cos(radians(cp.latitude)+radians(?3)), 2) + pow((radians(cp.latitude) - radians(?4)), 2))*6367)');
```

But I'm getting error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 172: Error: Expected end of string, got 'sqrt'
```

How do i use sql functions in dql?

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine dql does support the SQRT function but only in SELECT, WHERE and HAVING clauses so it won't work in your query where it appears in the ORDER BY clause. The other functions, POW, RADIANS and COS are not explicitly supported by dql.

There is a method for adding your own functions to the dql language (the documentation gives an example for the MySQL FLOOR function - see section 13.5.5 of the [DQL Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)) However it is unclear from the documentation whether these are also restricted to the SELECT, WHERE and HAVING clauses.

An alternative in this case is to use [Doctrine Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/native-sql.html).

Comment: I tried with native query and math functions work. But I've a one to many join on one of the tables 'specialization'. I'm not able to understand how to map it in ResultSetMapping. Docs show only an example with one to one.

Comment: @Shewtanka I don't think adding a one to many to the ResultSetMapping should be much different from adding a one to one. Are you getting any specific errors when you try this? If so perhaps you could add what you tried and what went wrong to your question?